# Can I derive a Bicep template from a deployed resource?

Tags: azure, infrastructure-as-code, azure-bicep

I am evaluating Bicep for IAC. To get started quickly, I was wondering whether I can derive templates from my resources that are already live and deployed in Azure?

Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can decompile an existing JSON template to a .bicep file with the `az bicep` cli:

```
az bicep decompile --file template.json
```

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/decompile?tabs=azure-cli#decompile-from-json-to-bicep).

Comment: I started to download the ARM deployment template 3 hours ago, it's still pending to download, I don't suppose there is another (maybe unsupported) way?

Comment: @baouss 3 hours, how are you downloading that?! you should just go in the deployment of the resource to fetch the template used

Comment: It's taking 3h to generate itself. Resource group >> Automation. It just might have timed-out

Comment: @baouss that sounds like a different issue; your original problem was solved

Comment: Mostly right, I have just accepted it. Though sometimes ARM templates do not export everything about a resource. Therefore I asked whether bicep had a more direct API to derive from resources, rather than transpile files.